# Is it possible to compare two fields from different types on a Query DSL?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I'm new to ElasticSearch and I'm struggling with this question. Basically what I want to do is sort of like this (SQL Example):

```
SELECT A.id
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

I want a Query that returns all of the info from TableA, but only if the id from TableA is equal to an id from TableB. 
I've read a lot of Query Filter fields and I think I might use the [Term Field](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-term-query.html) but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

This answer was given by Adrien Grand on a ElasticSearch group:

> This SQL query is a join and in general elasticsearch does not support joins.
>
> If the id field is your PK, you might be able to do it by indexing B as a child of A (using parent/child) and then searching for all documents in A that have a child in B.