# How to do a join negative query in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 indexes in my Elasticsearch setup.

- **index_a**
- **index_b**

`index_a` has a field `location` and have about 1000 documents where as `index_b` has a field `city` and have about 600 documents.

I want to find out all the `locations` from `index_a` that are not in the `city` field in `index_b`. What query should I make to achieve the above ?

Comment: You perform two queries (select all from index_b, then perform the search on index_a). Elasticsearch is not able to "join" in any way two indices in a single query, and rather prefers having denormalized data, **or** use `nested` or parent-child relationships.

Comment: As @AndreiStefan mentioned this maybe better handled at the application level.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799207/is-it-possible-to-compare-two-fields-from-different-types-on-a-query-dsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You perform two queries: select "all necessary info" from **index_b**, then perform the search on **index_a** using the "info" from **index_b**.

Elasticsearch is not able to "join" in any way two indices in a single query, and rather prefers having denormalized data, or use nested or parent-child relationships.